# find that excludes directories that are number dash number

Tags: regex, linux, find

I'm trying to write a find command that excludes directories that are numbers dash number, but allow other directories.

Sample directories

```
./135888897-135954433/
./135888897-135954434/
./135888897-135954435/
./BLAG-DEF-JOB1/
./TOM-DEPLOYDEV-JOB1/
./FRANK-RELEASE-JOB1/
./STEVE-RELEASE-JOB1/
```

Here's part of my find command. I can't seem to get it to skip the number directories.

```
find . -type f ! -regex '\./[0-9]+\-[0-9]+/*'
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.*` instead of `*`.
When useing regex a `*` means 'match the preceding token 0 or more times'

This will result in the following command:

```
find . -type f ! -regex '\./[0-9]+\-[0-9]+/.*'
```

**Update**: I also thought you forgot to escape the `/` in your command, but after doing a little bit of research it seems escaping `/` is not necessary when using the `find` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
find . -type f ! -regex '\./[0-9]+-[0-9]+/.*'
```